# Ajax call at last

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

in my jquery function i have two ajax call with serverside method and its working fine,
problem is ajax call at last amd after ajax line of code run but this lines of code depand on

```
function Rbook(b) {

var one = $(b).attr("data-oneislcc");
var two = $(b).attr("data-twoislcc");
var trip1 = $(b).attr("data-oneinfo");
var trip2 = $(b).attr("data-twoinfo");
var owflt = "l";
var inflt = 'r';
var owjdata = $(b).attr("data-ow");
var iwjdata = $(b).attr("data-iw");
var llccreturn, rlccreturn;
var lres, rres;
$("#fadeing").css("display", "block");
$("#fade").css("display", "block").css("height", $(document).height / 2);
if (one == 'true') {


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Search-RoundResult.aspx/FareQuoteMethod",
        data: "{'ALcode':'" + trip1 + "','flt':'" + owflt + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function OnSuccess(response) {
            if (response.d != null) {
                lres = response.d;
                if (response.d == "sessionExpire") {
                }
                else {
                    var data = new Array()
                    data = response.d.split("oldfare=");
                    llccreturn = owlcc(data[0], data[1])
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("Please Try agian.");
            }
        },
        Error: function errer(msg) {
            $("#fade").css("display", "none");
            $("#light").css("display", "none");
            alert(msg.d)
        }

    });

}
else {
    llccreturn = ownonlcc(owjdata);
}
if (two == 'true') {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Search-RoundResult.aspx/FareQuoteMethod",
        data: "{'ALcode':'" + trip2 + "','flt':'" + inflt + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function OnSuccess(response) {


            if (response.d != null) {
                if (rres == "sessionExpire") {

                }
                else {
                    var data = new Array()
                    data = response.d.split("oldfare=");
                    rlccreturn = iwlcc(data[0], data[1])

                }

            }
            else {
                alert("Please Try agian.");
            }
        },
        Error: function errer(msg) {
            $("#fade").css("display", "none");
            $("#light").css("display", "none");
            alert(msg.d)
        }

    });

}
else {
    rlccreturn = iwnonlcc(iwjdata);
}

if (llccreturn == 'farechange' || rlccreturn == 'farechange') {
    $("#farechange").css("display", "block");
    $("#fade").css("display", "block");

}
if (llccreturn == 'nofarechange' || rlccreturn == 'nofarechange') {
    window.location = "reviewbooking.aspx?trip1=" + $(b).attr("data-oneinfo") + "&iwlcc=" + $(b).attr("data-oneislcc") + "&trip2=" + $(b).attr("data-twoinfo") + "&owlcc=" + $(b).attr("data-twoislcc");
}}

var owlcc = function (jdata, oldfare) {
//Some Calulation
    retrun 'farechange';
}

var ownonlcc = function (jdata) {     //Some Calulation 
    retrun 'nofarechange'}

var iwlcc = function (jdata, oldfare) {     //Some Calulation 
    return 'farechange'}


var iwnonlcc = function (jdata) { retrun 'nofarechange'}
```

if run this code its run this line of code then rest so condition not validate 
i dont know where i m doing wrong

```
if (llccreturn == 'farechange' || rlccreturn == 'farechange') {
    $("#farechange").css("display", "block");
    $("#fade").css("display", "block");

}
if (llccreturn == 'nofarechange' || rlccreturn == 'nofarechange') {
    window.location = "reviewbooking.aspx?trip1=" + $(b).attr("data-oneinfo") + "&iwlcc=" + $(b).attr("data-oneislcc") + "&trip2=" + $(b).attr("data-twoinfo") + "&owlcc=" + $(b).attr("data-twoislcc");
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual code or have you retyped it? There are many typing mistakes you should fix first (retrun instead of return etc)

Comment: I just remove the unwanted code that's its if its something wrong i m really sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't understand asynchronous javascript. When you do an ajax call, it sends the request, then continues running the code and only later runs the success handler. Otherwise, it wouldn't be able to do anything at all until the response came back, since javascript is single-threaded.

The `Rbook` function does the following: First, get lots of information from the DOM; then, send some ajax requests (and set handlers to run when the response comes back); then possibly make some changes to the DOM, depending on the values of `llccreturn` and `rlccreturn` (but they're still `undefined`). It's only when the ajax response comes back and the success handler is run that these variables are set, but by then it's too late.

If you want to run some code after hearing the ajax response, put it in the success handler (or call it from the success handler). In this case, it's further complicated by the fact that you don't want to run the code until *both* ajax responses have arrived, and also by the fact that you might just run `iwnonlcc` or `ownonlcc` synchronously instead of doing an ajax call. I'd say the easiest way to fix this would be to wrap the code you want to run at the end inside a function and an `if` block like this:

```
function dataWasReceived() {
    if (llccreturn !== undefined && rlccreturn !== undefined) {
        if (llccreturn == 'farechange' || rlccreturn == 'farechange') {
            $("#farechange").css("display", "block");
            $("#fade").css("display", "block");

        }
        if (llccreturn == 'nofarechange' || rlccreturn == 'nofarechange') {
            window.location = "reviewbooking.aspx?trip1=" + $(b).attr("data-oneinfo") + "&iwlcc=" + $(b).attr("data-oneislcc") + "&trip2=" + $(b).attr("data-twoinfo") + "&owlcc=" + $(b).attr("data-twoislcc");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, every time you set the value of `llccreturn` or `rlccreturn`, call this function:

```
rlccreturn = iwlcc(data[0], data[1])
dataWasReceived();
```

and:

```
rlccreturn = iwnonlcc(iwjdata);
dataWasReceived();
```

etc.

I'm also concerned about this line (appears twice):

```
data: "{'ALcode':'" + trip2 + "','flt':'" + inflt + "'}",
```

You probably wanted to apply the argument as an object, not a JSON string representing that object:

```
data: {ALcode: trip2, flt: inflt},
```

(Incidentally, the string you gave wasn't valid JSON anyway, since it used `'` instead of `"`.)